# How to import a raster into PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, raster, gdal, postgresql

I'm trying to follow the [instructions](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-svn/RT_reference.html#RT_Loading_Rasters) here to load a raster into a PostGIS database:

```
python raster2pgsql.py -s 4269 -I -r *.tif -F myschema.demelevation -o elev.sql
```

I understand that I replace `*` with the path to my raster, but I don't understand the part `myschema.demelevation` or `elev.sql`. Should I have my own schema for this file? And what does the `elev.sql` part mean?

I also read through the [gdal PostGIS raster driver](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/frmts_wtkraster.html) to try and understand this with more examples. Similarly, they suggest loading a raster `katrina`

```
python raster2pgsql.py -r /path/to/katrina.tif -t katrina -l 1 -k 64x64 -o katrina.sql -s 4326 -I -M
```

Using my current setup, I tried loading the `katrina` raster in:

```
    python2.6 ~/src/postgis-2.0.0SVN/raster/scripts/python/raster2pgsql.py -r ~/tmp/katrina.tif -t katrina -l 1 -k 64x64 -o katrina.sql -s 4326 -I -M
```

However, I got the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/src/postgis-2.0.0SVN/raster/scripts/python/raster2pgsql.py", line 34, in <module>
    from osgeo import gdal
  File "/home/lib/python2.6/GDAL-1.8.1-py2.6-linux-i686.egg/osgeo/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/lib/python2.6/GDAL-1.8.1-py2.6-linux-i686.egg/osgeo/__init__.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: /home/lib/python2.6/GDAL-1.8.1-py2.6-linux-i686.egg/osgeo/_gdal.so: undefined symbol: GDALSetRasterUnitType
```

I don't fully understand these errors mean; when I compiled `gdal` should I have specified an argument for `GDALSetRasterUnitType` ?

More generally, I'm having difficulty understanding why I am not specifying the database that I am trying to load this data into.

---

After following MerseViking's advice I ran:

```
python /usr/lib/postgresql/8.4/bin/raster2pgsql.py -r /home/celenius/Downloads/katrina.tif -t katrina -l 1 -k 64x64 -o katrina.sql -s 4326 -I -M
```

which returned the following output:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
 Summary of GDAL to PostGIS Raster processing:
------------------------------------------------------------
Number of processed raster files: 1 (/home/celenius/Downloads/katrina.tif)
List of generated tables (number of tiles):
1   katrina (256)
```

Then I ran:

```
psql -d test -f katrina.sql - U postgres -W
```

which returned the following:

```
    addrastercolumn                                                                                                                                                                                        
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 public.katrina.rast srid:4326 pixel_types:{8BUI,8BUI,8BUI} out_db:false regular_blocking:true nodata_values:NULL scale_x:'0.029325513196481' scale_y:'-0.029325513196481' blocksize_x:'64' blocksize_y:'64' extent:POLYGON((-100.014662756598 9.98533724340176,-100.014662756598 40.0146627565982,-69.9853372434018 40.0146627565982,-69.9853372434018 9.98533724340176,-100.014662756598 9.98533724340176))
(1 row)

(END)
```

This message and a blinking cursor appear on screen. I assume that it is loading into the database, but I'm not sure. The `tif` file is just 3MB - I had assumed that it would not take long to load a file of this size but the blinking cursor has already been on the screen for ~1 hour. Has this crashed or do I just need to wait a long time? 
I have 4GB of RAM and a dual-processor of 2.5 GHz.

Comment: I have found that if I hit the key `q`, that it executes this command, and inserts the data into the database `test`. Is this normal behavior and should I be doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems there's a typo on that page; in the line:

```
python raster2pgsql.py -s 4269 -I -r *.tif -F myschema.demelevation -o elev.sql
```

The `-F` parameter should be `-t` which specifies the table name to import the data into. The part before the `.` is the optional schema name if you want your table in a schema other than `public`. The `-o` parameter specifies the file that is generated by the Python script. This file is the SQL representation of your table definition and the actual data from the source raster, so it can get pretty large. Once this file is generated, you need to run it through `psql -d <db_name> -f elev.sql` to actually populate the database, after which it can be deleted.

However, what strikes me as odd is that you're calling `raster2pgsql.py` from the PostGIS 2.0 *source* directory. Have you actually compiled (by running `make`) and installed (by running `make install` as root) PostGIS 2.0? Because it should be on your path, and IIRC the installer automatically updates your `PYTHON_PATH` environment variable.

As for the missing `GDALSetRasterUnitType`, the thing I would first check for is that you don't have an earlier version of GDAL libraries installed that Python is picking up instead of 1.8.1. Try `gdalinfo --version` [This site](http://community.webfaction.com/questions/5689/installing-gdal-for-postgis-20) may shed some light on your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions - I'll test it out. I am quite confused about how to call this script. I have run `make` and `make install`;I should have been calling it from `./bin/raster2pgsql.py`. I am using shared hosting that does not have root access, but I can install programs. When I run `gdalinfo --version` I get `GDAL 1.5.3, released 2008/09/09`; which is the server version; I have installed GDAL 1.8.1 but it's not being picked up by this command.