# Python gdal import error

Tags: python, gdal, installation, import

I installed gdal from source using steps from this answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/21739/60378 (ommiting first line sudo apt-get install build-essential python-all-dev as it did not work for me). Everything went without errors. When i try to import osego or gdal it gives me error: undefined symbol: GDALSetRasterUnitType

```
    >>> import gdal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/GDAL-1.9.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/gdal.py", line 2, in <module>
    from osgeo.gdal import deprecation_warn
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/GDAL-1.9.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/osgeo/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/GDAL-1.9.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/osgeo/__init__.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/GDAL-1.9.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/osgeo/_gdal.so: undefined symbol: GDALSetRasterUnitType
```

Server is using fedora core 14, which I cannot upgrade right now. What could be wrong? Is there any simpler gdal installation method?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are building version `1.9.0` instead of the recent stable release? What was the output of `make` and `install`? Alternatives are for instance the [precompiled Fedora GDAL package](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/package/gdal/) or [conda](http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html), which comes with it's own Python binary package manager, which also contains GDAL.

Comment: No, there is no particular reason for 1.9.0. Output of make and install didn't seem to have errors. Thanks for package links, I'll try this later, as I am quite new in fedora packages, using Ubuntu mostly. Before installing should I remove previously installed GDAL?

Comment: Have you had a look see at this?

http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16515/how-to-import-a-raster-into-postgis

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem and I solved this problem by downgrading of GDAL. I had GDAL 2.2.3 and I downgrade it to version GDAL 2.1.0.

You can install it with:

`pip install GDAL==2.1.0`

or only for user:

`pip install --user GDAL==2.1.0`